# string insertions at index position in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am coding quine mcclusky algorithm in javascript. I took inputs as decimal values, for example 0,2,6,7. I can have variables from 1 to 5 in my code. 1 being a or 'a' and 5 being a, b, c, d, e.

In my code I converted the inputs to binary values. For example for 0, 2, 6, 7. I have an array with binary equivalent ["000", "010", "110", "111"].

I made another logic for counting 1's. I take every element of the binary array and count the number of 1's. These are saves in an object in the following way:

```
{0:"000",1:"010",2:"110",3:"111"}
```

This might not be very difficult but, if I have the input **0, 2, 4, 3, 5** and I run a loop such that:

```
function onesgrp(str)
{

var tmp= str.split(""); //splits the string for example "010" into [0 1 0]
for(i=0;i<len.str;i++)
{
if(tmp[i]==1)

index++;

else 
continue;

}
}

This function will tell how many 1's each string has and index value will represent the no. of 1's.
```

I want to insert this string into 'index' position in object. if `index=2`, I want to insert the array into index 2 and so on. Then if I have another string with`index=2`, I want to add it in obj position 2 such that I do not overwrite the previous string. At the end I have an obj with each index having the strings with 'index' number of 1's. But the problem is I have different length variables.

Can anyone tell me a way to do this? I found some javascript versions of quine mcclusky algorithm, but I find them too hard to understand. Since I am a beginner, and not very comfortable with advanced javascript. Does anyone know a simpler code for logic minimization using quine mccluskey? I would be really obliged.

Another description of my question:

> I am coding quine mcclusky algorithm in javascript. A am trying a
>   write code such that I have an array of binary strings, for each
>   element of the array. I count the number of 1's in the string. I can
>   have variable length strings max upto 5, but for every input all
>   strings in the array will be of same length. For each input I want
>   to group the strings by "no. of 1's" in an object. For example, I have
>   a binary string `0001`, it has one '1' in it. This string would be saved
>   at index 1 in object. Second, I have another string `0010` this
>   should also be added to index 1, but it should not overwrite the
>   previous string saved. I have for example `1010` it would go to
>   index 2 in object. After I assign all the strings of array to object
>   with each index of object shows the number of '1s' in the strings at
>   that key position. I want to compare `obj[0]` elements with other
>   key positions, and if the elements differ in only one position, example
>   `0000` and `0001` differ by one bit position, I want to save `0000` in
>   another obj. Following the above method until I find all the prime
>   implicants.

Comment: I've tried to understand what question you're asking and not been able to figure it out.  Perhaps you could take another shot at describing the particular question you want help with.

Comment: hi jfriend00, i edit my post, plz see at the bottom of the post

Comment: I think you need to simplify your question abit. It's difficult to tell what you are asking. Maybe add some code of what you have tried? That would be helpful